# Tabela Temporária CodeIgniter + JS

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, tabela-html

Eu tenho a tela `cad_novo_produto.php` onde contém uma tabela e quando clicar em novo irá abrir um *popup* chamado `cad_componentes_produto` onde serão inseridas informações , e ira retornar a tela `cad_novo_produto.php` com a tabela preenchida pelos dados do *popup*.

**cad_novo_produto.php:**

```
<?php

echo "";
      if($this->session->flashdata('cadastrook')):
        echo "<div class='alert alert-block'>
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button><p> ".$this->session->flashdata('cadastrook')."</p></div>";
    endif;

echo "<div id='titulo' class='row-fluid'> 
        <div class='container'>
            <h4>Cadastro de  Produtos</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='box_fluid' class='row-fluid'>
        <div  class='container-fluid'>
            <div id='formulario_componente'>";

        echo"
            <div class='span6 offset2'>";

                echo form_open('cadastrar_produto/cad_novo_produto',array('class' => 'form-horizontal'));

                echo"<div class='controls controls-row'>
                                <div class='span6'>
                                    <p class='span10'>Código:</p>";

                                echo form_input(array('id'=>'inputCodigo','name'=>'Codigo', 'placeholder'=>'Digite o codigo do produto', 'class'=>'span12'), set_value('Codigo'));
                                echo form_error('Codigo', '<div class="erro_form">', '</div>'); 
                            echo"</div>


                            <div class='span6'>
                                <p class='span12'>Identificação do Produto:</p>";
                                echo form_input(array('id'=>'inputNome','name'=>'Nome', 'placeholder'=>'Digite a identificacao do produto', 'class'=>'span12'), set_value('Nome'));
                                echo form_error('Nome', '<div class="erro_form">', '</div>'); 
                            echo"</div></div>


                <div class='controls controls-row'>
                            <div class='span12'>
                                <p class='span10'>Características:</p>";
                                echo form_input(array('id'=>'inputCaracteristicas','name'=>'Caracteristicas', 'placeholder'=>'Digite a caracteristica do produto', 'class'=>'span12'), set_value('Caracteristicas'));
                                echo form_error('Caracteristicas', '<div class="erro_form">', '</div>'); 
                            echo"</div></div>

                <div class='controls controls-row'>
                            <div class='span12'>
                                <p class='span12'>Coleção:</p>";
                                echo form_input(array('id'=>'inputColecao','name'=>'Colecao', 'placeholder'=>'Digite a colecao', 'class'=>'span12'), set_value('Colecao'));
                                echo form_error('Colecao', '<div class="erro_form">', '</div>'); 
                            echo"</div></div></div>


          <div id='formulario_componente'>


                <table class='table table-condensed'>

                    <tbody>

                    <thead>

                    <caption></caption>";


                    //echo anchor_popup('cadastrar_produto/cad_novo_produto', 'Novo', array());

                           echo" <tr class='cad_componente'>
                                    <td>#</td>
                                    <td>Componente</td>
                                    <td>Tipo de Componente</td>
                                    <td>Unidade de Medida</td>
                                    <td>Quantidade</td>
                                    <td>Valor Unitário</td>
                                    <td>Excluir</td>

                            </tr>



                                <tr class='cad_componente'>
                                        <td class='link'>";echo anchor_popup('cadastrar_produto/cad_componentes_produto','<i class=" icon-plus icon-white"></i><i class="novo">Novo</i>',$attributes);echo"</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td class='tot_prod'>Total do Produto:</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

                <div class='control-group'> 
                        <p class='span6'></p>
                        <div class='controls'>";
                        echo form_submit(array('name'=>'entrar','class'=>'btn'), 'Cadastrar');
                        echo form_input(array('id'=>'inputEstoque','name'=>'FK_Id_Estoque', 'type'=>'hidden'), set_value('FK_Id_Estoque',$idestoque));
                    echo "</div>
                </div>
                    </div>";


            echo form_close();
        echo"
    </div></div></div>";?>
```

Já na página **cad_componentes_produto.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script> 

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$componente = $this->sistema_model->do_get_array('objeto_componente');
$unidade_medida = $this->sistema_model->do_get_array('unidade_medida');
$material = $this->sistema_model->do_get_array('material_componente');
$cor = $this->sistema_model->do_get_array('cor_componente');


echo "";
if($this->session->flashdata('cadastrook')):
echo "<div class='alert alert-block'>
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button><p> ".$this->session->flashdata('cadastrook')."</p></div>";
  endif;
echo "<div id='titulo' class='row-fluid'> 
    <div class='container'>
      <h3></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='box_fluid' class='row-fluid'>
    <div  class='container-fluid'>
      <div id='formulario_componente'>";
      $attributes = array('class' => 'span6 offset3', 'id' => 'form_prepare');
        echo form_open('cadastrar_produto/cad_componentes_produto',array('class' => 'span6 offset3'));
          echo"
            <div class='controls controls-row'>
              <div class='span12'>
                <p class='span12'>Componente:</p>
                <select name='FK_Id_Componente' id='componente'class='span12'>
                <option value='0'>Selecione</option>}
                option";

                foreach ($componente as $row):
                  echo"<option value='";
                    echo $row['Id_Objeto_Componente'];
                  echo"''>";
                    echo $row['Nome_Objeto'];
                  echo"</option>";
                endforeach;
                echo "</select>";
                echo form_error('FK_Id_Componente', '<div class="erro_form">', '</div>'); 
              echo"</div></div>

            <div class='controls controls-row'>
              <div class='span6'>
                <p class='span12'>Tipo de Componente:</p>
                <select name='FK_Id_Material_Componente'class='span12'>
                <option value='0'>Selecione</option>}
                option";

                foreach ($material as $row):
                  echo"<option value='";
                    echo $row['Id_Material_Componente'];
                  echo"''>";
                    echo $row['Nome_Material'];
                  echo"</option>";
                endforeach;
                echo "</select>";
                echo form_error('FK_Id_Material_Componente', '<div class="erro_form">', '</div>'); 
              echo"</div>

              <div class='span6'>
                <p class='span12'>Unidade de Medida:</p>
                <select name='FK_Id_Unidade_Medida' class='span12'>
                <option value='0'>Selecione</option>}
                option";

                foreach ($unidade_medida as $row):
                  echo"<option value='";
                    echo $row['Id_Unidade_Medida'];
                  echo"''>";
                    echo $row['Nome_Unidade_Medida'];
                  echo"</option>";
                endforeach;
                echo "</select>";
                echo form_error('FK_Id_Unidade_Medida', '<div class="erro_form">', '</div>'); 
              echo"</div></div>



            <div class='controls controls-row'> 
              <div class='span6'>
                <p class='span12'>Cor:</p>
                <select name='FK_Id_Cor' class='span12'>
                <option value='0'>Selecione</option>}
                option";

                foreach ($cor as $row):
                  echo"<option value='";
                    echo $row['Id_Cor'];
                  echo"''>";
                    echo $row['Nome_Cor'];
                  echo"</option>";
                endforeach;
                echo "</select>";
                echo form_error('FK_Id_Cor', '<div class="erro_form">', '</div>'); 
              echo"</div>

            <div class='span6'>
                <p class='span12'>Quantidade:</p>
                <div class='controls'>";
                  echo form_input(array('id'=>'inputQuantidade','name'=>'Quantidade', 'placeholder'=>'', 'class'=>'span12'), set_value('Quantidade'));
                  echo form_error('Quantidade', '<div class="erro_form">', '</div>'); 
              echo"</div>
              </div>

          <div id='titulo' class='row-fluid'> 

            <div class='control-group'> 
              <p class='span12'></p>
              <div class='controls'>";
              echo form_submit(array('name'=>'entrar','class'=>'btn btn-primary'), 'Cadastrar');
              echo form_input(array('id'=>'inputEstoque','name'=>'FK_Id_Estoque', 'type'=>'hidden'), set_value('FK_Id_Estoque',$idestoque));
            echo "</div>
          </div>
          </div>
            </div>";

        echo form_close();
      echo "</div>
    </div>";
?>
</body>
```

**Dúvida:** Como faço para pegar o valor do *dropdown* na página `cad_componentes_produto` que vem do banco por JS  e inserir na página `cad_novo_produto.php` na tabela temporária.

Comment: O teu código está uma grande trapalhada. Pelo que me pareceu a primeira acho que estás a misturar código PHP com HTML de forma errada.

Comment: Desculpe, coloquei apenas o trecho do código já respondi com o código completo!

Comment: não responda, faça [edit] na sua pergunta e altere da forma que quiser.

Comment: Venha para o Laravel